# how to resolve flutter List data inquire

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My database is firebase

database structure is Follower > docId > {follower : [ {uid : P4HXDFEeDFTU8bzJCRhNPDZLO6m1 , crDate: }], uid : userUid}

and this is my Follower inquire code

```
Obx(
  () {
    if (_followerCtrl.followerInfoLstByUid.isNotEmpty) {
      if (_followerCtrl.followerInfoLstByUid[0].follower
          .contains('P4HXDFEeDFTU8bzJCRhNPDZLO6m1')) {
        return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 16, 0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              color: black,
            ),
            height: 24,
            width: 82,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('팔로우',
                  style: TextStyle(color: white)),
            ));
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  },
)
```

and this is my Controller code

```
{
  void fetchFollowerLstByUid(String uid) {
    _followerApi.fetchColDataByUid(uid).listen((event) {
      loading(true);
      followerInfoLstByUid(event.docs
          .map<FollowerInfo>((doc) =>
              FollowerInfo.fromMap(doc.id, doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList());
      loading(false);
    });
  }

  RxList<FollowerInfo> followerInfoLstByUid = <FollowerInfo>[].obs;
}
```

I coded as above.
I want inquire 'P4HXDFEeDFTU8bzJCRhNPDZLO6m1' in my database

plaese help me,,,

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? And note that if data is not loading correctly, we'll need to see how you access the Firestore API for loading data (which probably is in your `fetchFollowerLstByUid` function).